# Wide table in two-column doc: error ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup

Tags: tables, two-column

I am trying to create a table which spans both columns of a two column document based on the IEEEtrans document class. However I am receiving the following error which I cannot explain:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.719 \end{table*}
```

Here is the table:

```
\begin{table*}
    \centering
      \caption{Penalty functions used in Optimisation}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{c c c c c}
            \toprule
            Aspect  & Notation & Limit & Penalty Function & Comments \\
            \midrule
            RMS Current Density & 6~Amm\textsuperscript{-2} & $L_{\text{JRMS}}$ & $S_C$ & \\
            Peak Current Density & 10~Amm\textsuperscript{-2} & $L_{\text{JMAX}}$ & $S_C$ & \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
        \label{tab:penfcns}
\end{table*}
```

The document builds with no errors if I comment out the table. line 719 is the line containing the:

```
\end{table*}
```

## EDIT - MINIMAL EXAMPLE

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
      \caption{Penalty functions used in Optimisation}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{c c c c c}
            Aspect  & Notation & Limit & Penalty Function & Comments \\
            RMS Current Density & 6~Amm\textsuperscript{-2} &  & $S_C$ & \\
            Peak Current Density & 10~Amm\textsuperscript{-2} &  & $S_C$ & \\
        \end{tabular*}
        \label{tab:penfcns}
\end{table*}



\end{document}
```

The combination of subfigure and fixltx2E seems to be the problem. I probably should be using subfig anyway.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), since this code doesn't give errors when inserted in a sample document.

Comment: I have found that the error disappears if I comment out the fixLaTeX2E package which I was using. Not sure yet though if this will cause me other problems.

Comment: I don't get errors even loading **fixltx2e**; a MWE is needed.

Comment: It seems that the subfigure package and fixltx2E don't like each other. The solution is to use subfig I think.

Comment: Yes, **subfigure** is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for the help though, I will try put more effort into solving my problems myself next time before asking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use package `subfig` instead of the outdated  subfigure. The documentation is available with running `texdoc subfig`.